# Is that a normal memory usage of a C# application - and can I change it?

Tags: c#, postgresql, kubernetes, entity-framework-core, memory-leaks

We have a microservice application in which a lot of services juist caring about data from databases and given workflows with them.
It is not unusual to get a high rate of requests (e.g. 100 per second), which is fine for now. We started to have a look at our memory behaviour and want to understand it.

We trace it with DotMemory:

[image]

In that we are watching a given gRPC C# .Net 8.0 Application with a request that is looping endless over one of our data services.
The services reads out 3 entites, compares and does minor data things in the RAM and creates a new entity.

So a few things here:

1. As we start very slow at the basic application of ~150MB the first bunch of requests will bring the memory to 350MB before the GC seems to collect the first time and every X seconds (around ~30seconds).
2. Even after the GC hit the Heap Generation 0 will drop very low but the memory used will be there as unmanaged memory and never be lowered in total.
3. The total memory, even after the GC collection, will grow every ~2000 requests for a few MB.

Questions:

a) Can I give my application a limit of Ram that is allowed to use?
b) Can / should I change the GC collection timing to a lower time?

The goal of the questions is here to reduce the total amount of ram, e.g. from 500MB to 300MB.

c) Is it correct that the growing rate of 10MB/2000Requests endlesly could be a memory leak that will mean it will grow endlesly and therefore sometime run against a Out of mem exception?

Comment: not sure about your application, but if you feel it should use less memory (according to your overall application usage) then you should dig into your app queries, as there might be queries that loading unnecessary data to the memory. Try to minimize that data by filtering the queries and only load what's necessary to the memory and release it when it's done.

Comment: @iSR5  Thank you, we already filter a lot and just get the smales amount of data we need.

Comment: Sounds like there might be unnecessary allocations going on. You should investigate what objects are being allocated and try to reduce it.

Comment: You should probably tag this with "dotmemory", as your question hinges on knowing what the heck it means by "unmanaged".